# ggplot multiple y for x

Tags: r, ggplot2

a) I want to create a bar plot with multiple y for x.

```
df<-data.frame(x=rep(c("x1","x2","x3","x4"),each=6),
           Legend=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"),
           y1=c(2843,2843,2843,900,1200,1000,2843,2843,2843,900,1200,1000,2843,2843,2843,900,1200,1000,2843,2843,2843,900,1200,1000),
           y2=c(3000,3000,3000,NA,NA,NA,3000,3000,3000,NA,NA,NA,3000,3000,3000,NA,NA,NA,3000,3000,3000,NA,NA,NA))

df2<-melt(df,id=c("x","Legend"))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=x,y=value,fill=Legend)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")

p
```

The problem is now that my `y1` value for example `x1` and `a` seem to be not plotted. Only the `y2` values for `a` and `x1`are visible. I need 9 bars per `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, and `x4`.

2. Another question: Is it possible to rectify the bars inside `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4`?

Comment: One solution for a is to use facets: `facet_wrap(~ variable)`

Comment: define "rectify"

Comment: the bars inside x1,x2,x3,x4 are too close to each other. Is it possible that there is more distance between the bars inside x1,x2,x3,x4?

Comment: @PoGibas thanks. `facet_wrap` is an interesting solution. But is it possible to have all bars in one plot?

Comment: try `fill = interaction(Legend, variable)`